# How to turn off voice dialler Huawei Honor 7

Tags: phone-app, voice-command, huawei-honor-7

I looked over all settings and couldn't find any way to turn off automatic voice dialler. How do I do it? My phone calls people on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to turn this off if you switch off "voice wakeup" completely.

Answer (score 1):

On Huawei Honor 5:
To disable voice dialer

Settings > Smart Assistance > Voice Control (disable)

Answer (score 0):

In my EMUI it was in Contacts / Settings / Fast Calling

Answer (score -1):

Just go to Settings > Apps > System Apps > Voice Dialer and press Disable.

Comment: There's no such option on Honor 7 on EMUI.

Comment: Yeah the emui systems a bit different. One of my phones runs it too so I'll tweak around with it and let you know when I figure it out.